# Replace every letter in a string using dictionary values

Tags: python

coders of the internet,

The goal of this assignment was to replace the letters of a sequence with their opposite. 'A' would be 'U', 'C' would be 'G', and vice versa. Here is the string that I came up with so far, but the output is wrong. I can't find a pattern in the output, so I can't reverse-engineer the problem.

```
sequence = input('Please enter a sequence: ')
def reverse(sequence):
  dic = { ' A ' : ' U ' , ' G ' : ' C ' , ' C ' : ' G ' , ' U ' : ' A ' }
  for i in range( len ( sequence ) ):
    if sequence[i] in dic.keys():
      sequence = sequence.replace(sequence[i], dic[sequence[i]])
  return sequence
reverse(sequence)
```

Does anyone know how to simply return turn an input (let's just use "GUGU"), and make the code return the output: "CACA"?

Comment: Take a look at [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Comment: The problem is that you first replace all `U` with `A`, then later you replace all `A` with `U`. So it goes back to the original.

Answer (score 1):

When you have circular replacements, you need to only convert each letter once.  The translate method can do that for you (better than replace):

```
dic = { ' A ' : ' U ' , ' G ' : ' C ' , ' C ' : ' G ' , ' U ' : ' A ' }

sequence = sequence.translate({ord(k):ord(v) for k,v in dic.items()})
```

You could also use maketrans to setup the mapping:

```
mapping = str.maketrans("AGCU","UCGA")

sequence  = sequence.translate(mapping)
```

without translate or replace, you could use the dictionary on each individual character and join the converted characters:

```
sequence = "".join(dic.get(c,c) for c in sequence)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing two issues:

1. `replace` affects all occurrences. That `i` is only used for evaluating the arguments (`sequence[i]` and `dic[sequence[i]]`), but once they are evaluated, the call is equivalent to e.g. `sequence.replace("A", "U")`, and then all occurrences of A are replaced with U, not just the once at index i.
2. Keys and values in the dictionary are wrapped with spaces. Assuming the sequence is something like `ACCAGUUA`, there are no matches, due to those spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.

```py
# Convert input to list format
sequence = list(str(input('Please enter a sequence: ')))

# Define keys
keys = {
    "a": "u",
    "g": "c",
    "c": "g",
    "u": "a"
}

# Create the reverse function
def reverse(sequence: list):
    # Iterate by enumeration and item in sequence list
    for i, letter in enumerate(sequence):
        if letter in keys: # If the letter has a translation
            sequence[i] = keys[letter] # Replace that value
    return ''.join(sequence) # Turn it back into a string

# Pass old list into reverse function
new_sequence = reverse(sequence)
print(new_sequence, type(new_sequence))

# Response: caca <class 'str'>
```

It may contain a few extra steps but clearly outlines how to achieve what you were looking for, step-by-step. The process is essentially:

1. Convert sequence to `list`.
2. Iterate the list and replace values based on `keys`.
3. Turn the list back into a string, and return the string.